# How do you create a model with an array of values?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I need to set up a model that is capable of storing an undefined number of serial numbers that are associated with only one tool.

```
class Tool(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=25)

class SerialNumber(models.Model):
tool = models.ForeignKey(Tool)
serial = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

The idea is that a tool can have multiple serial numbers. My problem is that these serial numbers have to somehow be permanently tied to the tool they're created with. I somehow to be able to query the serial number table based on a tool's ID.

I'm new to the django framework and database relationships, so any and all help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is for `SerialNumber` to have a `ForeignKey` back to `Tool`. You can then find all of a tool's serial numbers with `tool.serialnumber_set.all()`.

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be good the way you have it. Each SerialNumber is related to a specific Tool via a ForeignKey.

When the time comes to query the serial numbers, get out [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships). An example:

```
SerialNumber.objects.filter(tool__name="Hammer")
```

This would return all the SerialNumbers that belong to the Tool "Hammer".